# Sendgrid node js not sending email. Program has no error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

I am trying to set up an email contact page on my heroku website using sendgrid. I have tried the code with the helper mailer and the one without; however, both do are not able to send an email to my email address. I added my sendgrid API key as a variable in my heroku app settings and also imported the username and password.
My email process starts when the user click on a button. I have an action to a post route within the form element, and I use body parser to retrieve the input values from the user (message, their email address, and their message). Within my post route, I call a function in my email.js file that wraps the code from sendgrid.

//My html using handlebars.

```
<div class = "mainDiv" id = "sectionAbout">
            <h1 class="mainDivH1" id = "AboutMe">{{ ContactLi }}</h1>
                <form action="/email" method="POST">
                    <label for="fullName">{{ formName }}</label> <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="fullName">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="subject">{{ formSubject }}</label> <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="subject">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="email">{{ formEmail }}</label> <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="message">{{ formMessage }}</label> <br><br>
                    <textarea rows="15" cols="80" type="text" name="message id="textbox"></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button id="but" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
        </div>
```

//The code for the POST route

```
var email = require('../mail/email');

router.post('/email', function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.fullName;
    var emSubject = req.body.subject;
    var senderMail = req.body.email;
    var message = name + " " + req.body.message;

    var myEmail = 'examplee@yahoo.com';

    email.send(emSubject, senderMail, message, function(){
        res.redirect('/contact');   
    });
});
```

//email.js

```
 var helper = require('sendgrid').mail
 var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

 var email = {

    send: function(emSubject, senderMail, message, callback){

            var from_email = new helper.Email(senderMail);
            var to_email = new helper.Email('helper@yahoo.com');
            var subject = emSubject;
            var content = new helper.Content("text/plain", message);
            var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

            var request = sg.emptyRequest({
              method: 'POST',
              path: '/v3/mail/send',
              body: mail.toJSON()
            });
            console.dir("request");
            console.dir(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));

            sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
              if(error){
                console.log(error);
              }     
              console.log(response.statusCode)
              console.log(response.body)
              console.log(response.headers)
              callback(error);
            });

    }
 }

 module.exports = email;
```

Comment: There's no errors logged? Do the show up in the sendgrid dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you added your Sendgrid API key as an env var, and imported your username and password. You should not have to do any of that. Just add the Sendgrid add-on to your Heroku account as follows:

```
heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
```